# There are more factors than what I have in the X axis being labeled

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, x-axis

I am plotting a simple violin plot that shows violins of a variable for 2 years, so i just need the "2017" and "2018" to appear in the X axis, but more tick marks are appearing, from 2016.5, 2017.0, 2017.5... until 2018.5. In the "year" column in my data i only have the two years that i want to plot. I don't understand why is it showing like this. Here is my code and an image of the graph I am getting!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x44A.png)

```
sum.data <- ddply(df, .(Field), summarize, mean.TF = mean(TF, na.rm = T))

(violin <- 
    ggplot(df, aes(Year, TF)) +
    geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(Year))) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom ="point", shape=18, size=2) +
    labs(x= NULL, y= "Total FAME") +
    facet_grid(Field ~.) +
    geom_hline(data = sum.data, aes(yintercept = mean.TF), linetype = 3) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,300,50)) +
    theme.custom)
```

Comment: Give more information about data. Run this `dput(yourdf)` command in R  and paste the output here.

Comment: Try `ggplot(df, aes(factor(Year), TF))`

Comment: The first line - "Year" is not a factor in the aes(Year, TF), so it is numeric.  Make it a factor in the data frame and then you don't have to worry about it in the plot call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because `Year` is a numeric variable, and ggplot made that separation based on the values, if you had more years probably that would not happen. Here are two solutions.

### Example data

```
df <-
tibble(
  x = rep(2014:2015, each = 100),
  y = c(rnorm(100),rexp(100))
)
```

### Original code

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+
  geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(x)))
```

[image]

## Solutions

### Transform Year in a factor/character

That is a nice solution, because also solves the aesthetic `fill`, it could complicate some other geometry but that is very specific.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x = as.factor(x)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+
  geom_violin(aes(fill = x))
```

### Add a scale for x axis

Using scale you can set whatever `labels` or `breaks`, but you still need to transform the variable for the aesthetic `fill`.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+
  geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(x)))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2014:2015)
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I am new to this and my process has been a little slow. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
(violin <- df %>%
    mutate(Year = factor(Year)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(Year, TF)) +
    geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(Year))) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom ="point", shape=18, size=2) +
    labs(x= NULL, y= "Total FAME") +
    facet_grid(Field ~.) +
    geom_hline(data = sum.data, aes(yintercept = mean.TF), linetype = 3) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,300,50)) +
    theme.custom)
```